# Could you let me know "Unable to trigger default handler prompt prior to runtime permissions" from Google Console?

Tags: android, speech-recognition, google-developers-console

I'm making a app with Speech Recognizer.

And I upload to Google Console App as default assistant app.

But My app was rejected by Google Console and This is the reason.

"Unable to trigger default handler prompt prior to runtime permissions
If your app is a default handler, the default handler prompt must precede the runtime permission prompt.

Based on our review, your app doesn’t appear to properly trigger the default handler prompt prior to the runtime permissions prompt.
Please add the default handler prompt prior to any runtime permissions prompt."

Could you let me know what mean is and solution?